# Issue with put API in mean stack application but working fine in postman

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, api

I removed **AuthenticationHeader** it still not working fine because i dont have token in my localhost, i'm just activating email and tried many solutions but couldn't solved it.

**ActivateComponent.ts:**

```
export class ActivateComponent implements OnInit {

  currentUrl;
  constructor(
    private _auth: AuthService, 
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, 
    private _router: Router
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("activate component's ngOnInIt loaded");
    this.currentUrl = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params;
    console.log(this.currentUrl.token);
    this._auth.activateAccount(this.currentUrl.token);
  }
}
```

In AuthService I'm calling **API** in activateAccount.
**AuthService:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response} from '@angular/http';
import { tokenNotExpired } from 'angular2-jwt';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  authToken;
  user;
  options;
  domain = "http://localhost:8080/";

  constructor(private _http: Http) {

  }

  createAuthenticationHeaders() {
    this.loadToken();
    this.options = new RequestOptions({
      headers: new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'authorization': this.authToken
      })
    });
  }

  loadToken() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    this.authToken = token;
  }


  activateAccount(token) {
    this.createAuthenticationHeaders();
    return this._http.put(this.domain + 'authentication/activate/' + token, this.options).map(res => res.json());
  }

}
```

**Authentication API:**

http://localhost:8080/authentication/activate/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImJha2FyIiwiZW1haWwiOiJiYWthcm9wc3RAZ21haWwuY29tIiwiaWF0IjoxNTM2MDY0MDQ3fQ.6rONcRU5RwCMaZfAiQe0sWiJ4o1DyrvP5RT5YGnjH-w

When i hit this **api** from **postman** when have token in the end after activate, it works fine and send me response in json format like:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "Account Activate"
}
```

but when i call this from my angular app it doesn't work.

Actually when user register account i am sending **email** to the user email, and i want that when user click on the link which he/she **recieve** in email will change the **active** field in **Schema** to true, which was **false** in start. when i hit api from postman it set it to true, which means backend API is working fine but method of calling api from angular is not good.

```
router.put('/activate/:token', (req, res) => {

  User.findOne({
    temporarytoken: req.params.token
  }, (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      res.json({
        success: false,
        message: 'Token is invalid'
      });
    } else {
      var token = req.params.token;
      jwt.verify(token, config.secret, (err, decoded) => {
        if (err) {
          res.json({
            success: false,
            message: 'Error during verification'
          });
        } else if (!user) {
          res.json({
            success: false,
            message: 'Activation link expired'
          });
        } else {
          user.temporarytoken = false;
          user.active = true;
          user.save((err) => {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
            } else {
              output = `
                                    Hello <strong> ${user.username} </strong>,
                                    <br> <br> Your Account has been Scuessfully Activated!.
                                    `;
              var email = {
                from: 'Localhost Staff, staff@localhost.com',
                to: user.email,
                subject: 'Localhost Account Activated',
                text: `Hello <strong> ${user.username} </strong>,
                                        <br> <br> Your Account has been Scuessfully Activated!.`,
                html: output
              };

              client.sendMail(email, function(err, info) {
                if (err) {
                  console.log(error);
                } else {
                  console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
                }
              });
              res.json({
                success: true,
                message: 'Account Activate'
              });
            }
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are giving token in headers and in the url at the same time. You should not. In your case (depending on your API) you don' t need to add token to headers because your API is not waiting for it. And you would better use GET instead of PUT.
Change in you frontend from:

```
createAuthenticationHeaders() {
   this.loadToken(); // <- To remove
   this.options = new RequestOptions({
     headers: new Headers({
       'Content-Type': 'application/json',
       'authorization': this.authToken  // <- To remove
     })
   });
}


activateAccount(token) {
  this.createAuthenticationHeaders();
  // To change from PUT to GET
  return this._http
             .put(this.domain + 'authentication/activate/' + token, this.options)
             .map(res => res.json());
}
```

to:

```
 createAuthenticationHeaders() {
   this.options = new RequestOptions({
     headers: new Headers({
       'Content-Type': 'application/json'
     })
   });
}


activateAccount(token) {
  this.createAuthenticationHeaders();
  return this._http
             .get(this.domain + 'authentication/activate/' + token, this.options)
             .map(res => res.json());
}
```

And change in you API too from:

```
router.put('/activate/:token', (req, res) => {
   ...
});
```

to:

```
router.get('/activate/:token', (req, res) => {
   ...
});
```

But you will better learn how to add token to headers and how to manage it in the API with [passportJS](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/).